# How to create button to make changes to boolean in dynamic list?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

```
@Published var storedMedicines: [Medicine] = [
    Medicine(Title: "Medicine 1", Description: "Lower blood sugar", date: .init(timeIntervalSince1970: 1664724035), isTaken: false),
    Medicine(Title: "Medicine 1", Description: "Lower blood sugar", date: .init(timeIntervalSince1970: 1664720930), isTaken: false),
    Medicine(Title: "Medicine 1", Description: "Lower blood sugar", date: .init(timeIntervalSince1970: 1664720990), isTaken: false),
    Medicine(Title: "Medicine 1", Description: "Lower blood sugar", date: .init(timeIntervalSince1970: 1664720990), isTaken: false),
]
```

This is the dynamic list that I create and I want a button to make the isTaken from false to true. I have no idea where to start.

Comment: This question has not enough code or information to receive the right answer (what is `Medicine`, a class or a struct?) and you didn't show the bare minimum effort of googling "SwuiftUI button". Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are using an ObservableObject, take a look at this:

```
    import SwiftUI

        struct Medicine: Identifiable {
            let id = UUID()
            let Title: String
            let Description: String
            let date: Date
            var isTaken: Bool
        }

        class MedicineViewModel: ObservableObject {
            @Published var storedMedicines: [Medicine] = [
                Medicine(Title: "Medicine 1", Description: "Lower blood sugar", date: .init(timeIntervalSince1970: 1664724035), isTaken: false),
                Medicine(Title: "Medicine 2", Description: "Lower blood sugar", date: .init(timeIntervalSince1970: 1664720930), isTaken: false),
                Medicine(Title: "Medicine 3", Description: "Lower blood sugar", date: .init(timeIntervalSince1970: 1664720990), isTaken: false),
                Medicine(Title: "Medicine 4", Description: "Lower blood sugar", date: .init(timeIntervalSince1970: 1664720990), isTaken: false),
            ]
            
            func updateButtons() {
                storedMedicines = storedMedicines.map({
                    var medicine = $0
                    medicine.isTaken.toggle()
                    return medicine
                })
            }
            
        }

        struct ButtonUpdate: View {
            @StateObject var viewModel = MedicineViewModel()
            var body: some View {
                
                VStack {
                    ForEach($viewModel.storedMedicines) { $medicine in
                        HStack {
                            Text(medicine.Title)
                            
                            Text(medicine.Description)
                            
                            Text(medicine.isTaken.description)
                        }
                    }
                    
                    Button("Toggle Medicines") {
                        viewModel.updateButtons()
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                }
            }
        }
```

[image]